# Set default folder for saving bookmarks in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I'm using Firefox 29.0.1 and would like to change the default folder a bookmark is saved to.

Currently when saving a bookmark (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> hotkey) the folder is always "Bookmarks Menu" but I want it to be "Unsorted Bookmarks". It's really annoying and tiring to always have to select that folder when setting a bookmark.

Comment: No add-on is possible, since FF57 doesn't let add-ons access the base engine. From the words of the developer of the [Change Bookmark Recent Folder List Length add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-bookmark-recent-folder-/) which also manipulates the Bookmarks : "There is **no possibility** that this add-on can be updated to work as a WebExtension ... This add-on ... can not be implemented under the limited capabilities permitted to WebExtensions, which have a very limited ability to affect the Firefox user interface."

Comment: Reading all these add-on developers' opinions on the new WebExtension system replacing legacy add-ons is just depressing. Lots of great addons will no longer work in what is essentially going to be a Chrome clone. If you rely on a lot of add-ons that won't survive the change, it's time to switch to other forks based on Firefox like [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/) and [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/)

Answer (score 5):

I did some personal searching and I couldn't find an option to change the default bookmark location. This post in Mozilla support is quite old but seems to confirm that: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/797132

There is a tip in that post that may interest you.

> For me, installing add-ons which fix Firefox quirks isn't the way to go in this case.
>
> There have to be better solutions. By experimenting a bit, I found
>   two: 1. Right-click anywhere on the page and press M. 2. CTRL+D will
>   also select Bookmarks Menu and since ALT+D is shortcut for 'Done', you
>   can practice this and bookmark pages lightning-fast
>
> Only left-clicking the star in the address bar results in your
>   bookmark being placed straight in the Unsorted Bookmarks.
>
> This behavior frustrates me as well. It doesn't do what I want and I
>   can't customize it. Thus, I can only ignore the star completely for
>   the purposes of saving bookmarks.
>
> from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/797132#answer-154294

Answer (score 0):

[As of Firefox 85](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1432604), the browser now remembers the last bookmark location.

Comment: Sadly, as of FF 86, this still works only for a single bookmark, not for bookmark folders. ( Select multiple tabs, then try to "Bookmark Tabs ..." - they will go to a named folder ). I suppose this is what still partially fuels bug reports like [1412263](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1412263). However, it can be solved by changing `browser.bookmarks.defaultLocation` to `menu` ( see here: [1319979](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1319979#answer-1379992) ), and then letting Firefox to remember the last used destination for a single bookmark as "Other Bookmarks".

Answer (score -1):

[**Add Bookmark Here ²**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-bookmark-here-2/) is a good add-on which can achieve what you need. Main features include:

- Expand all fields in Bookmark Dialog.
- Customize the position of "Add Bookmark Here" & "Open All Tabs".
- **Remember the last selected folder when you bookmark a page.**
- Insert bookmarks from the top of Menu.
- **Add a bookmark without showing the Bookmark Dialog.**
- Single-click the Star to show the Bookmark Dialog.
- Resize the Folder-Tree, Tags-List, Description-Field in Bookmark Dialog.
- Customize the location of Unsorted Bookmarks Folder.
- Show the Tags in Inline.
- Middle-click Bookmark Star can Open Library to Organize Bookmarks.
- Middle-click on a folder to add bookmark into the folder.
- Prevent [ENTER] key to close Bookmark Dialog when editing in Tags/Description field.
- Auto Sort Folder By Name. (Right-click on any Folder > "Properties" > "Sort By Name".)
- Show the bookmark saved path in Star button tool tips.

Comment: "If you know a suitable extension, make sure it is a WebExtension as legacy extensions are deprecated in November 2017, when Firefox 57 is released.". [The extension isn't compatible](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-bookmark-here-2/versions/) and I wasn't able to install it on Firefox 56.0.2 either.